# CUDA 5 and CUDA 4.2 in parallel

Tags: .net, cuda, gpgpu

This might seem like a stupid question but I would like to know if I can have both Version CUDA 5 and CUDA 4.2 installed?

I'm about to install CUDA 5 but I would still like to use my older Projects where I have been using CUDA 4.2 and Visual Studio 2010. What do I have to consider?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have both CUDA 4.1 and CUDA 5.0 installed, I'm using both with Visual Studio 2010 and I think there should be no problem also in the case of CUDA 4.2.
Go to Project -> Build Customization and select the appropriate version of CUDA to rebuild your project.